# update a column of multiples to equal another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table I am trying to update. In my table if a column has a duplicate it is grouped together with its matches. One of those docs is the original. I need to update my table to make the group Id's equal the original document. So all the docs must have the same unified title if they are in the same group. For example OCR0000000006, OCR0000000008 would both have unified title 06000146.pdf.

Here is sample of my table:

```
DOCID           Duplicate_Group Duplicate_Principal Duplicate_Similarity Unified_Title
OCR0000000001   OCR0000000001        Yes                         100    06000093.pdf
OCR0000000002                        No                            0    06000110.pdf
OCR0000000003   OCR0000009554        No                           94    06000847.pdf
OCR0000000004   OCR0000000006        No                           95    06000117.pdf
OCR0000000005                        No                            0    06000849.pdf
OCR0000000006   OCR0000000006        Yesn                        100    06000146.pdf
OCR0000000007                        No                            0    06000852.pdf
OCR0000000008   OCR0000000006        No                           93    06000175.pdf
```

Here is what I have last tried this gives me the "Subquery returned more than 1 value." error. I was also able to update all the original docs but not the duplicates with the proper value.

```
update tt 
set tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group = (select unified_title from                                     #tempsquirrel tt
where  tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group in (select yy.docid from #tempballs yy) and Textual_Near_Duplicate_Principal = 'yes')
from #tempsquirrel tt 
where tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group in (select yy.docid from #tempballs yy)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the results you're getting are expected, but simply have multiple values, you could use a GROUP BY or DISTINCT in your subquery that is returning more than one record to remove the duplicate rows.

The error is probably due to it trying to insert one value into the assignment of tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group

It would be like:

```
set tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group = (select unified_title from                                     #tempsquirrel tt
where  tt.Textual_Near_Duplicate_Group in (select yy.docid from #tempballs yy) and Textual_Near_Duplicate_Principal = 'yes' GROUP BY yy.docid)
```

Comment: I tried several versions of this and I'm only getting errors

Comment: Hmm. I'm not a SQL Server expert, but if that's not working you may have to remove the sub queries and out it in a derived table.